# Tensorflow feeding in images is extremely slow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to wrap my head around feeding in a custom dataset. The Tensorflow [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/) gave an object where I could just request another batch of training data and feed that in, so I tried to do something similar. I created a dataset object ds, which exposes the function get_alphabet which uses a WholeFileReader to read a png, and uses tf.image.decode_png to get a Tensor. It returns a list of Tensors as data (train_x), and a list of tensors as one_hot labels (train_y). The problem is that evaluating these images takes a ridiculous amount of time, and it eventually gets to the point where I'm waiting 10 seconds to see the "2" printed after the "1" gets printed. How do I speed this up?

```
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
for i in range(NUM_ITERATIONS):
    train_x, train_y = ds.get_alphabet(BATCH_SIZE) 
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    inputs = np.ndarray(shape=(BATCH_SIZE, FEATURE_SIZE), dtype=int)
    outputs = np.ndarray(shape=(BATCH_SIZE, NUM_LABELS), dtype=int)

    print('1')
    for image in range(BATCH_SIZE):
        inputs[image] = train_x[image].eval(session=sess).flatten()
        outputs[image] = train_y[image].eval(session=sess).flatten()
    print('2')

    if i % 10 == 0:
        current_accuracy = accuracy.eval(session=sess, feed_dict={ x: inputs, y: outputs })
        print("accuracy of {0:.2f}% on {1}th iteration".format(current_accuracy * 100, i))
    if i == 0:
        print(inputs.shape)
        print(outputs)

coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: What does the contents of `get_alphabet` look like?

Comment: Posting all of the code might be nice. What is `BATCH_SIZE`?

Comment: BATCH_SIZE is how many examples I want, currently set to 100. get_alphabet is [here](http://pastebin.com/YFHQc2Wm)

Answer (score 0):

## Use TFRecord with new Dataset API(released as part of TF 1.4 version) to resolve your problem

## TFRecords:

```
-TensorFlow's own binary format
-Its format uses a mixture of its Records format and and Protocol Buffers(or Protobuf)
-Record is simply a binary file that contains tf.train.Example Protobuf Objects
-Protocol Buffers, it as a way to serialize data structures, given some schema describing what the data is.
```

### Advantage of TFRecords:

```
-They make better use of disk cache.
-They are faster to move around.
-They can store data of different types (so you can put both images and labels in one place)
```

First convert everything to TFRecords(i.e. Both Image and corresponding labels into TFrecord) file, Then you can use TFRecordDataset API to retrieve the data with batching from TFrecord file

**Steps to creating TFrecords**

1) Use tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter to open the tfrecords file and start writing 
2) Before writing into tfrecords file,the image data and label data should be converted into proper datatype(like float)
3) Now the datatypes are converted into tf.train.Feature
4) Finally create an Example Protocol Buffer using tf.Example and use the converted features into it.
5) Serialize the Example using serialize() function.
6) Write the serialized Example

Eg code:

```
from matplotlib.image import imread
tfrecord_filename = 'TFrecord.tfrecord'

writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecord_filename)
sess = tf.Session()
input_files = _get_file_names() # get list of image file names
for input_file in input_files:
    img = imread(input_file)
    #tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad - used to resize image of different size
    img = sess.run(tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(img, 
                  target_height=480, target_width=640))
    label = <get_correspondinglabels>
    input_feature = { 'label': _int64_feature(label),
                  'image': _bytes_feature(img.tostring()) }
    feature = tf.train.Features(feature=input_feature)
    example = tf.train.Example(features=feature)
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()

def _int64_feature(value):
     return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))
def _bytes_feature(value):
     return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))
```

**Steps for reading from TFRecords:**

1) Read the TFRecord file name 
2) Create TFRecordDataset by providing the TFrecord file name
3) Create the Parse function for decoding and do any preprocessing work in input data
4) Create batching, repeat(no of epoch) and shuffling using dataset created in previous steps
5) Create the Iterator to fetch required inputs as a batch(i.e. mini-batch)

Eg code:

```
def input_model_function():
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecord_filename)
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
    dataset = dataset.batch(20)# you can use any number of batching
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    sess = tf.Session()
    batch_images, batch_labels = sess.run(iterator.get_next())
return {'x':batch_images}, batch_labels

def _parse_function(example_proto):
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, tfrecord_features)
    # Get the image as raw bytes.
    image_raw = parsed_features['image']
    # Decode the raw bytes so it becomes a tensor with type.
    image = tf.decode_raw(image_raw, tf.uint8)
    # The type is now uint8 but we need it to be float.
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    #Get the label associated with the image.
    label = parsed_features['label']
return image, label
```

Finally input batched Dataset into Model(created using any Pre-Made Estimator or Custom Estimator API)